# Total Minutes by Hour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two fields in a data table - "startTime" and "endTime."  These two fields represent a duration of time the user spent on a particular task.  These are varchar fields. So, let's say we have a startTime of "21:05:00" and an endTime of "22:09:00."  I need the code to sum the total number of minutes spent in hour 21, and the 22 hundred hour separately (i.e. 9 minutes). So, not just a simple minute difference, but a breakdown by hour.

What might be the best way to do that?

Thus far, I have created a table that will return all possible hours in a 24-hour period. Here's a sample:

```
Hour    startTime                endTime
0       2015-01-01 00:00:00.000  2015-01-01 01:00:00.000
1       2015-01-01 01:00:00.000  2015-01-01 02:00:00.000
2       2015-01-01 02:00:00.000  2015-01-01 03:00:00.000
```

And I have converted the startTime field from varchar to dateteime and called it sessionHour:

```
Convert(datetime, startTime) As sessionHour
```

Additionally, I was able to get the hour of the startTime by doing:

```
DateAdd(Minute, 60 * (DateDiff(Minute, 0, startTime) / 60), 0)  As hourOf
```

Beyond that, I am lost as to how to parse out the minutes per hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. You just need to combine the numbers table with the data. I'll use [`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.90).aspx) for it. Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2b77a/2/0) with the final solution.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @Durations TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime);

INSERT INTO @Durations VALUES
('2015-01-01 21:05:00', '2015-01-01 22:09:00'),
('2015-01-01 01:05:00', '2015-01-01 01:20:00'),
('2015-01-01 11:05:00', '2015-01-01 13:09:00'),
('2015-01-01 15:05:00', '2015-01-01 17:50:00'),
('2015-01-01 16:30:00', '2015-01-01 17:20:00');
```

I'll use `datetime` type from the beginning, since you've converted your `varchar` values to proper `datetime`.

I'll use a table of numbers. It should have as many rows as the longest duration in hours in your data. It could be more than 24. In general, it is useful to have such table in a database for other reports.

```
DECLARE @Numbers TABLE (Number int);
INSERT INTO @Numbers VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
-- Number of rows in this table should be more than the longest duration in hours
```

I'll need some reference point in time for removing minute part of the `datetime`. It could be any date-time as long as it doesn't have minutes and seconds.

```
DECLARE @VarStart datetime;
SET @VarStart = '2000-01-01';
```

### **Main step - Expand the data**

```
SELECT *
FROM
    @Durations AS D
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT N.Number
        FROM @Numbers AS N
        WHERE N.Number <= DATEDIFF(hour, StartTime, EndTime)
    ) AS CA_Number
ORDER BY ID;

ID   StartTime              EndTime                Number
1    2015-01-01 21:05:00    2015-01-01 22:09:00    0
1    2015-01-01 21:05:00    2015-01-01 22:09:00    1
2    2015-01-01 01:05:00    2015-01-01 01:20:00    0
3    2015-01-01 11:05:00    2015-01-01 13:09:00    0
3    2015-01-01 11:05:00    2015-01-01 13:09:00    1
3    2015-01-01 11:05:00    2015-01-01 13:09:00    2
4    2015-01-01 15:05:00    2015-01-01 17:50:00    0
4    2015-01-01 15:05:00    2015-01-01 17:50:00    1
4    2015-01-01 15:05:00    2015-01-01 17:50:00    2
5    2015-01-01 16:30:00    2015-01-01 17:20:00    0
5    2015-01-01 16:30:00    2015-01-01 17:20:00    1
```

You can see that we created several rows for each original row depending on the duration of the original row. The rest is simple arithmetic.

**Minutes per hour**

```
SELECT *
    ,DATEDIFF(minute, MaxStart, MinEnd) AS MinutesPerHour
FROM
    @Durations AS D
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT N.Number
        FROM @Numbers AS N
        WHERE N.Number <= DATEDIFF(hour, StartTime, EndTime)
    ) AS CA_Number
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            DATEADD(hour, CA_Number.Number, StartTime) AS HourStart
            ,DATEADD(hour, CA_Number.Number+1, StartTime) AS HourEnd
    ) AS CA_HourEnd
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        -- Truncate to 1 hour.
        SELECT
            DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, @VarStart, HourStart), @VarStart) AS HourStartFinal
            ,DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, @VarStart, HourEnd), @VarStart) AS HourEndFinal
    ) AS CA_HourEndFinal
    -- Intersect intervals [StartTime, EndTime] with [HourStartFinal, HourEndFinal]
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN StartTime > HourStartFinal THEN StartTime ELSE HourStartFinal END AS MaxStart
            ,CASE WHEN EndTime < HourEndFinal THEN EndTime ELSE HourEndFinal END AS MinEnd
    ) AS CA_Intersect
ORDER BY ID;
```

In `CA_HourEnd` and `CA_HourEndFinal` I calculate the hour boundaries using the `Number`. Then intersect two intervals and calculate the number of minutes for each intersection. This is the result set:

```
ID   StartTime              EndTime                Number    HourStart              HourEnd                HourStartFinal         HourEndFinal           MaxStart               MinEnd                 MinutesPerHour
1    2015-01-01 21:05:00    2015-01-01 22:09:00    0         2015-01-01 21:05:00    2015-01-01 22:05:00    2015-01-01 21:00:00    2015-01-01 22:00:00    2015-01-01 21:05:00    2015-01-01 22:00:00    55
1    2015-01-01 21:05:00    2015-01-01 22:09:00    1         2015-01-01 22:05:00    2015-01-01 23:05:00    2015-01-01 22:00:00    2015-01-01 23:00:00    2015-01-01 22:00:00    2015-01-01 22:09:00    9
2    2015-01-01 01:05:00    2015-01-01 01:20:00    0         2015-01-01 01:05:00    2015-01-01 02:05:00    2015-01-01 01:00:00    2015-01-01 02:00:00    2015-01-01 01:05:00    2015-01-01 01:20:00    15
3    2015-01-01 11:05:00    2015-01-01 13:09:00    0         2015-01-01 11:05:00    2015-01-01 12:05:00    2015-01-01 11:00:00    2015-01-01 12:00:00    2015-01-01 11:05:00    2015-01-01 12:00:00    55
3    2015-01-01 11:05:00    2015-01-01 13:09:00    1         2015-01-01 12:05:00    2015-01-01 13:05:00    2015-01-01 12:00:00    2015-01-01 13:00:00    2015-01-01 12:00:00    2015-01-01 13:00:00    60
3    2015-01-01 11:05:00    2015-01-01 13:09:00    2         2015-01-01 13:05:00    2015-01-01 14:05:00    2015-01-01 13:00:00    2015-01-01 14:00:00    2015-01-01 13:00:00    2015-01-01 13:09:00    9
4    2015-01-01 15:05:00    2015-01-01 17:50:00    0         2015-01-01 15:05:00    2015-01-01 16:05:00    2015-01-01 15:00:00    2015-01-01 16:00:00    2015-01-01 15:05:00    2015-01-01 16:00:00    55
4    2015-01-01 15:05:00    2015-01-01 17:50:00    1         2015-01-01 16:05:00    2015-01-01 17:05:00    2015-01-01 16:00:00    2015-01-01 17:00:00    2015-01-01 16:00:00    2015-01-01 17:00:00    60
4    2015-01-01 15:05:00    2015-01-01 17:50:00    2         2015-01-01 17:05:00    2015-01-01 18:05:00    2015-01-01 17:00:00    2015-01-01 18:00:00    2015-01-01 17:00:00    2015-01-01 17:50:00    50
5    2015-01-01 16:30:00    2015-01-01 17:20:00    0         2015-01-01 16:30:00    2015-01-01 17:30:00    2015-01-01 16:00:00    2015-01-01 17:00:00    2015-01-01 16:30:00    2015-01-01 17:00:00    30
5    2015-01-01 16:30:00    2015-01-01 17:20:00    1         2015-01-01 17:30:00    2015-01-01 18:30:00    2015-01-01 17:00:00    2015-01-01 18:00:00    2015-01-01 17:00:00    2015-01-01 17:20:00    20
```

**Final query**

Finally, I sum the minutes grouping by an hour:

```
SELECT
    HourStartFinal
    ,SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, MaxStart, MinEnd)) AS SumMinutesPerHour
FROM
    @Durations AS D
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT N.Number
        FROM @Numbers AS N
        WHERE N.Number <= DATEDIFF(hour, StartTime, EndTime)
    ) AS CA_Number
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            DATEADD(hour, CA_Number.Number, StartTime) AS HourStart
            ,DATEADD(hour, CA_Number.Number+1, StartTime) AS HourEnd
    ) AS CA_HourEnd
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        -- Truncate to 1 hour.
        SELECT
            DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, @VarStart, HourStart), @VarStart) AS HourStartFinal
            ,DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, @VarStart, HourEnd), @VarStart) AS HourEndFinal
    ) AS CA_HourEndFinal
    -- Intersect intervals [StartTime, EndTime] with [HourStartFinal, HourEndFinal]
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN StartTime > HourStartFinal THEN StartTime ELSE HourStartFinal END AS MaxStart
            ,CASE WHEN EndTime < HourEndFinal THEN EndTime ELSE HourEndFinal END AS MinEnd
    ) AS CA_Intersect
GROUP BY HourStartFinal
ORDER BY HourStartFinal;
```

**Final result set**

```
HourStartFinal             SumMinutesPerHour
2015-01-01 01:00:00.000    15
2015-01-01 11:00:00.000    55
2015-01-01 12:00:00.000    60
2015-01-01 13:00:00.000    9
2015-01-01 15:00:00.000    55
2015-01-01 16:00:00.000    90
2015-01-01 17:00:00.000    70
2015-01-01 21:00:00.000    55
2015-01-01 22:00:00.000    9
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2b77a/2/0)

Comment: This works perfectly, and I appreicate the fiddle.  Thank you!  One thing I am not clear on is the "numbers" table and how it connects all of this?

Comment: `Numbers` table simply has consecutive numbers from 0 to something large enough. In my database it has 100K rows. You fill it once and use in many reports when needed. In this example I explicitly added few rows to it to make example work. In real system this table would have these numbers already and it would have primary key/unique index on the `Number` column. This table is joined to the main table using `CROSS APPLY` which creates several rows for each original row. For example, if duration in some row spans across 3 hours, this row would appear 3 times  after `CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 1):

While Vladimir Baranov's answer is correct, It uses way to many `CROSS APPLY`.

Another way to get the minutes by hour, can be using the fact that in a range of `starttime` and `endtime`, except for the first hour and the last all other hours will have `minutediff` of the hour as 60.

We can use this and construct our logic, Something like this.

```
DECLARE @UserTask TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),UserID INT,TaskID INT, StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime);

INSERT INTO @UserTask VALUES
(1,1,'2015-01-01 21:05:00', '2015-01-01 22:09:00'),
(1,1,'2015-01-01 01:05:00', '2015-01-01 01:20:00'),
(1,1,'2015-01-01 11:05:00', '2015-01-01 13:09:00'),
(1,1,'2015-01-01 15:05:00', '2015-01-01 17:50:00'),
(1,1,'2015-01-01 16:30:00', '2015-01-01 17:20:00'),
(2,2,'2015-01-01 21:05:00', '2015-01-01 22:09:00');

;WITH CTENum AS 
(
SELECT 1 rn UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), CTEHours as 
(
SELECT TOP 24 ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY c1.rn) - 1 rn FROM CTENum c1 CROSS JOIN CTENum c2
)
SELECT ID,UserID,TaskID,StartTime,EndTime,rn as DayHour,
CASE WHEN r_asc = 1 AND r_desc = 1 THEN DATEDIFF(minute,StartTime,EndTime) 
WHEN r_asc = 1 THEN 60 - DATEPART(minute,StartTime)
WHEN r_desc = 1 THEN DATEPART(minute,EndTime)
ELSE 60 END MinuteTime
FROM @UserTask
CROSS APPLY(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY rn ASC) r_asc,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY rn DESC) r_desc
FROM CTEHours C
WHERE C.rn BETWEEN DATEDIFF(hour,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),StartTime,112),StartTime) AND DATEDIFF(hour,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),StartTime,112),EndTime)
) N
ORDER BY ID,DayHour
```

Comment: You are right, I used `CROSS APPLY` a lot to illustrate how it is useful for complex formulas. I assumed that OP wanted to see this answer: 55 minutes for 21st hour; 9 minutes for 22nd hour when startTime="21:05:00" and endTime="22:09:00". Total duration is 55+9=64 minutes. Your query returns 5 minutes for 21st hour, not 55. You must have missed some comparison in your `CASE` formula. Besides, the solution doesn't work when duration goes across the midnight boundary. Try to change `2015-01-01 22:09:00` to `2015-01-03 22:09:00` in the source data.

Comment: @Vladimir - Good catch about the the initial hour duration. I missed `60 - x`. Yes, my solution works within the range of a single day :) . Based on OP's question and sample data, it doesn't look like he has records spanning different dates.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the `datepart()` function, it'll help you manipulate your dates more cleanly. For example:

```
select @endOfHour = dateadd(hour,
    1,
    datetimefromparts(
        datepart(year, @startTime),
        datepart(month, @startTime),
        datepart(day, @startTime),
        datepart(hour, @startTime),
        0,
        0,
        0));


select h.theHour, @startTime, @endOfHour, datediff(minute, @startTime, @endOfHour)
from ListOfHours as h
where datepart(hour, @startTime) = h.Hour;
```